# After replacing an array in a if conditions not returning new array

Tags: python, python-3.7

I am new to python. In this script I am updating an array.

```
def do_smoothing(input_csv, original):
    print(input_csv)

    for ins, rw in input_csv.iterrows():
        if(rw.start or rw.end != -999999):
            order_value_equal = comp(rw.Previous_Three, rw.Next_Three)
            two_equal = eval_tuples(rw.Previous_Three, rw.Next_Three)
            check_fist_fourth = chcek_offset0_and_offset4(rw.Previous_Three, rw.Next_Three,ins)
            check_two_zeros_onEither_side_val = check_two_zeros_onEither_side(rw.Previous_Three, rw.Next_Three,ins)

        if order_value_equal:
            original = np.array(original)
            original[rw.start + 1: rw.end -1] = get_maximum_value(rw.Previous_Three)
        if two_equal:
            original = np.array(original)
            original[rw.start + 1: rw.end -1] = get_maximum_value(rw.Previous_Three)
        if check_fist_fourth:
            original = np.array(original)
            original[rw.start + 1: rw.end -1] = get_firstvalue(rw.Previous_Three)
        if check_two_zeros_onEither_side_val:
            original = np.array(original)
            original[rw.start + 1: rw.end -1]= get_firstvalue(rw.Previous_Three)
        else:
            pass

    return original
```

In this, I am updating the `output` array every time, but while returning it is not returning the updated, it is returning the same as before. Can anyone help me with this?

Comment: Could you remove the code that's been commented out?

Comment: It seems to me that the conditions to edit the array aren't met. Hence the array is returned without modifications

Comment: Is the separation of conditionals intentional; are you avoiding the use of `elif` for a specific reason?

Comment: There is a possibility `order_value_equal` `two_equal` `check_fist_fourth` `check_fist_fourth` are all `False`. Have you checked their values?

Comment: conditions are getting true still

Answer (score 1):

Your question and code are somewhat unclear, so correct the following assumptions if they are incorrect.

- `input_csv` is a pandas DataFrame object derived from a CSV file. This is assumed on the basis that the `iterrows` method is a pandas method for that data type.
- `original` is a default Python `list` that is being converted into a numpy `array`.
- Methods like `comp`, `eval_tuples`, etc. are custom methods that produce boolean values.
- Methods like `get_maximum_value` and `get_firstvalue` are custom methods that produce an `int`, or another basic data structure.

Let's clean up the code a little bit to get a better idea of what's going on.

```
def do_smoothing_better(input_csv, original):
    print(input_csv)

    for ins, row in input_csv.iterrows():
        if row.start or row.end != -999999:
            order_value_equal = comp(row.Previous_Three, row.Next_Three)
            two_equal = eval_tuples(row.Previous_Three, row.Next_Three)
            check_fist_fourth = check_offset0_and_offset4(
                row.Previous_Three, row.Next_Three, ins
            )
            check_two_zeros_onEither_side_val = check_two_zeros_onEither_side(
                row.Previous_Three, row.Next_Three, ins
            )
        else:         # this fallback must be added so you don't end up
            continue  # with errors if no booleans are actuall initialized

        if order_value_equal or two_equal:  # both of these can be combined
            original = np.array(original)  # as they resulted in the same expression
            original[row.start + 1 : row.end - 1] = get_maximum_value(
                row.Previous_Three
            )

        if check_fist_fourth or check_two_zeros_onEither_side_val:  # as can these
            original = np.array(original)
            original[row.start + 1 : row.end - 1] = get_firstvalue(row.Previous_Three)
        else:
            continue

    return original
```

Adding proper `else` tests and formatting the second conditional as such should prevent the interpreter from dropping into the wrong block, and thereby producing an inaccurate value.

Comment: actually all the four conditions should go through each loop

Comment: Why? Both result in the the same blocks.